# Convert 3-Channel (BGR) Matrix to 4-Channel (ABGR) Matrix

Tags: java, opencv, android

I'm using the Java libraries to work with OpenCV and I want to convert a 3 channel matrix in BGR format to 4 channels in ABGR. It has to be ABGR a because I am using a [BufferedImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) class to display the image
 and the alpha channel must come before the colours.

Within the [Imgproc](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.1.0/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html) class there is a static method `cvtColor()` but it must take a code value to describe the conversion. In this case I want BGR to ABGR but there doesn't seem to be a conversion code for this, only with alpha after the colour channels [COLOR_BGR2BGRA](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.1.0/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#COLOR_BGR2BGRA).

Is there any other way or helper class that will do the conversion that I require?

Answer (score 1):

You can use split/merge methods to decompose/assemble image plains as you need.

Comment: Which class are they in?

Comment: Core class :    http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Core.html#merge(java.util.List, org.opencv.core.Mat)